# React - How to manage external link - which solution is better

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a React component which displays a product with three links. My product links redirect to internal link under react-router but for one product, I want to redirect to an external link. How to manage properly the external link?

For now, I have two solutions and don’t know which one is a better solution?

Here is what my react component `Product` render :

```
<article>
    <header>
        <Link className={s.link} to={link}>
        {cardImage}
        </Link>
    </header>
    <div>
        <h2>
            <Link to={link}>
            {title}
            </Link>
        </h2>
        <div>
            <Link to={link}>
            Shop Now
            </Link>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Here are my two solutions :

Solution 1:

Create LinkDuo component

```
const propTypes = {
    to: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

/**
 * Link that also works for external URL's
 */
export const LinkDuo = (props) => {
    return isExternal(props.to) ?
        <a href={props.to} {...props}/> // eslint-disable-line jsx-a11y/anchor-has-content
        :
        <Link {...props} />;
};

LinkDuo.propTypes = propTypes;
```

and replace Link by LinkDuo

```
<article>
    <header>
        <LinkDuo className={s.link} to={link}>
        {cardImage}
        </LinkDuo>
    </header>
    <div>
        <h2>
            <LinkDuo to={link}>
            {title}
            </LinkDuo>
        </h2>
        <div>
            <LinkDuo to={link}>
            Shop Now
            </LinkDuo>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Solution 2 :

```
const isExternal = !!link.match(/^http/);

<article>
    <header>
        {isExternal ?
            <a href={link} className={s.link}>{cardImage}</a>
            :
            <Link className={s.link} to={link}>
            {cardImage}
            </Link>
        }
    </header>
    <div>
        <h2>
            {isExternal ?
                <a href={link} className={s.link}>{cardImage}</a>
                :
                <Link to={link}>
                {title}
                </Link>
        }
        </h2>
        <div>
            {isExternal ?
                <a href={link} className={s.link}>{cardImage}</a>
                :
                <Link to={link}>
                Shop Now
                </Link>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Which one is a better solution in terms of reusability, maintainability, testability?

Comment: Solution 1 is higher order component so it is more reusable and maintainable.

Comment: The one that reuses the same code (e.g. does not copy-paste it) is the better one in terms of reusability.  ;)